# How to find ripple faucet coin for development

Tags: ripple, java, faucets

I'm developing an app with ripple. I need some faucet coin for ripple. How can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best solution. The link is: https://ripple.com/build/xrp-test-net/
We can generate new credential and it has 10000 xrp in testnet. The testnet websocket address is wss://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51233

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it these website but i guess it should work: http://satoshibakery.com/ripple-faucet.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using adblock and all faucet sites warning for disable it. I hate it.